# Remove text duplicate from nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html:

```
<div class="description">Example
    <div class="description">Foo
        <div class="description">Example 
            <div class="description"> Example </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to remove all duplicate text i.e:

```
   <div class="description">Example
      <div class="description">Foo</div>
   </div>
```

Nesting could go up to 8th level with the exact/identical element.

Comment: what you tried ? show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code to fulfill your need :

```
// first of all, looping of all target elements
$('.description').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim(); // this will first make clone of target, then remove all children of target and then get remaining text "without including unnecessary children text" and then trim "for remove unnecessary white space"
    $(this).find('.description').each(function(){ // Then looping of internal elements to check their text
        var subtext = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim(); // internal element's text "without including sub elements unnecessary text"
        if(subtext === text){ // compare target text and internal element's text : if both are identical, then we allow to remove internal element
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a bunch. If it's alright and not too much to ask can you please include an explanation to your answer?

Comment: You're a star! Thanks again.