# How to remove double text in an element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, text

Can you remove double text using jQuery? I have the following setup:

```
<td class="product-name">Instagram workshop - Instagram workshop</td>
    <td class="product-name">Product 4 - Product 4</td>
```

Can jQuery remove the ' - Instagram workshop' so that I have to following output:

```
<td class="product-name">Instagram workshop</td>
<td class="product-name">Product 4</td>
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove text duplicate from nested element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497971/remove-text-duplicate-from-nested-element)

Answer (score 1):

You could get all elements with the class of `product-name` and iterate over them using `.each()`. By using `.each()` you can access your current element that you're iterated on by using `$(this)`. This will provide a way for you to perform jquery methods as you have made `this` a jquery object.

As you want to modify the text from each of your `td` elements you can do this through the use of `.text()`. `text()` allows you to pass in a function which you can then `return` the result of the new text you would like to appear in your element. In the example below, I have used a `Set` with `.split()` to create a container of unique words (separated by a `-`). By spreading the set back into an array using the spread syntax (`...`) you can then join all the array elements (ie words) back into a larger string which would then no longer contain your duplicate words.

See example below:

```js
$(".product-name").each(function() {
  $(this).text(function(_, txt) {
    return [...new Set(txt.split(' - '))].join(' - ');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="product-name">Instagram workshop - Instagram workshop</td>
    <td class="product-name">Product 4 - Product 4</td>
    <td class="product-name">Product 1 - Product 2 - Product 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to use regex:

```
([^\-]+)\s*\-\s*\1
```

Here you capture group (in brackets) and then use callback reference to compare words. You can use this to search and replace content with `$1` - the first group withouth any characters in between